# execute script with parameters on linux boot

Tags: linux, startup, boot

I'm working with a `Debian` based `Linux`. Have a script that needs to be executed on boot. Found [these instructions describing on how it needs to be one](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html). My only difference is that I need to run a script with a parameter at bootup (myscript.sh --some-option 23). I can't use a wrapper script. I won't explain why, but I will only say that I just can't. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Run it from `/etc/rc.local`? Make a service unit for systemd to run it?

Comment: Is your system using systemd? (e.g. does running `systemctl` succeed?)

Answer (score 1):

The cron daemon has a `@reboot` command. That runs your script at reboot. So simply edit your crontab and add a line like this:

```
@reboot /your/script/test.sh
```

Comment: `cron` daemon is not available on my system.

Comment: @flashburn What prevents you from installing some kind of cron?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a system with systemd, this is easy enough. Create a new service file "foo.service":

```
[Unit]
Description=Powertop autotune

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/powertop --auto-tune # XXX replace with your command

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and then install it:

```
ln -s /home/kris/Scripts/systemd/powertop.service /lib/systemd/system
systemctl enable powertop
systemctl start powertop
```

Obviously your paths and particulars will be different. In particular, the `/lib/systemd/system` might not be the right place in your distribution.